# Unable to echo with different colors for batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, colors

When i run the batch file on VS code, the color does not appear and shows the raw code.

```
echo off
echo %ESC%[42mCan support unscramble your logs?%ESC%[0m
```

When i run the code manually, it does not show the color and show the raw code as well.

```
echo %ESC%[42mCan support unscramble your logs?%ESC%[0m
```

[image]

Any ideas? I'm on Windows 10, without admin rights.

Yesterday i tried to run this batch file on VS code and the color changed.

However for cmd.exe, it will still display the raw code without any colors.

Been referencing to multiple questions e.g.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the `ESC` environment variable:

```
for /F %a in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do @set "ESC=%a"
```

Then you can use it, e.g. as follows:

```
echo ^<ESC^>[4m %ESC%[4mUnderline Underline%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[32m %ESC%[32mGreen  Green  Green%ESC%[0m
echo ^<ESC^>[33m %ESC%[33mYellow Yellow Yellow%ESC%[0m
```

Result:

[image]

Test from a batch script using the following code snippet:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do (
  set "ESC=%%a"
)
echo ^<ESC^>[4m %ESC%[4mUnderline DisableDelayedExpansion%ESC%[0m

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

echo !ESC![101;93m STYLES !ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[4m !ESC![4mUnderline!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[0m !ESC![0mReset!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[1m !ESC![1mBold!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7m !ESC![7mInverse!ESC![0m
echo.
echo !ESC![101;93m NORMAL FOREGROUND COLORS !ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[30m !ESC![30mBlack!ESC![0m (black)
echo ^<ESC^>[31m !ESC![31mRed!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[32m !ESC![32mGreen!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[33m !ESC![33mYellow!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[34m !ESC![34mBlue!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[35m !ESC![35mMagenta!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[36m !ESC![36mCyan!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[37m !ESC![37mWhite!ESC![0m
echo.
echo !ESC![101;93m NORMAL BACKGROUND COLORS !ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[40m !ESC![40mBlack!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[41m !ESC![41mRed!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[42m !ESC![42mGreen!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[43m !ESC![43mYellow!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[44m !ESC![44mBlue!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[45m !ESC![45mMagenta!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[46m !ESC![46mCyan!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[47m !ESC![47mWhite!ESC![0m (white)
echo.
echo !ESC![101;93m STRONG FOREGROUND COLORS !ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[90m !ESC![90mWhite!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[91m !ESC![91mRed!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[92m !ESC![92mGreen!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[93m !ESC![93mYellow!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[94m !ESC![94mBlue!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[95m !ESC![95mMagenta!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[96m !ESC![96mCyan!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[97m !ESC![97mWhite!ESC![0m
echo.
echo !ESC![101;93m STRONG BACKGROUND COLORS !ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[100m !ESC![100mBlack!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[101m !ESC![101mRed!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[102m !ESC![102mGreen!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[103m !ESC![103mYellow!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[104m !ESC![104mBlue!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[105m !ESC![105mMagenta!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[106m !ESC![106mCyan!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[107m !ESC![107mWhite!ESC![0m
echo.
echo !ESC![101;93m COMBINATIONS !ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[31m                     !ESC![31mred foreground color!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7m                      !ESC![7minverse foreground ^<-^> background!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7;31m                   !ESC![7;31minverse red foreground color!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[7m and nested !ESC![31m !ESC![7mbefore !ESC![31mnested!ESC![0m
echo ^<ESC^>[31m and nested !ESC![7m !ESC![31mbefore !ESC![7mnested!ESC![0m
```

Comment: Ahh my bad! I missed out the first part while copying and paste.. Thank you for the clear explanations to a newbie!

Comment: @JosefZ This command doesn't work inside the IF statement?... when I put it in the IF, the message appears: "%ESC%[0m was unexpected at this time." How to make it work in IF?

Comment: @Clamarc The `… was unexpected at this time` message mostly appears in case of wrong syntax e.g. as `if 1 echo x` returns `echo was unexpected at this time`.

Comment: @JosefZ I fixed this and the warning message disappeared, but the command still doesn't show the colored message when inside the IF?!. I tried to put another slash closing the command, because of the IF slash, but it didn't work, the message only appears in color when it's out of the IF!?

Comment: @Clamarc Please feel free to ask another question about your issue (better at https://stackoverflow.com/) -and let me know here. It's hard to understand without seeing a relevant code snippet and its result…

Comment: @JosefZ I already opened a ask about this problem, see the link:
```https://superuser.com/questions/1714134/if-cancels-when-i-run-message-command-to-user```

Comment: @JosefZ there I question the cancellation of the IF that was resolved, but you can see my code with the message inside the IF, ok?

Comment: @JosefZ I saw your answer to the question from the link I sent you, it worked, thanks!

Comment: @Clamarc you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

there is of course many ways you can make use of ascii escape codes for color output, including using RGB color schemes. here is one such example.

```bat
@Echo Off & Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
mode 170,40
::: { Creates variable /AE = Ascii-27 escape code.
::: - %/AE% can be used  with and without DelayedExpansion.
    For /F %%a in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd')do set "/AE=%%a"
::: }

(Set \n=^^^
%=Newline DNR=%
)
::: / Color Print Macro -
::: Usage: %Print%{RRR;GGG;BBB}text to output
::: \n at the end of the string echo's a new line
::: valid range for RGB values: 0 - 255
  Set Print=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 (%\n%
    For /F "Delims=" %%G in ("!Args!")Do (%\n%
      For /F "Tokens=1 Delims={}" %%i in ("%%G")Do Set "Output=%/AE%[0m%/AE%[38;2;%%im!Args:{%%~i}=!"%\n%
      ^< Nul set /P "=!Output:\n=!%/AE%[0m"%\n%
      If "!Output:~-2!"=="\n" (Echo/^&Endlocal)Else (Endlocal)%\n%
    )%\n%
  )Else Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion ^& Set Args=
::: / Erase Macro -
::: Usage: %Erase%{string of the length to be erased}
  Set Erase=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 (%\n%
    For /F "Tokens=1 Delims={}" %%G in ("!Args!")Do (%\n%
      Set "Nul=!Args:{%%G}=%%G!"%\n%
      For /L %%# in (0 1 100) Do (If Not "!Nul:~%%#,1!"=="" ^< Nul set /P "=%/AE%[D%/AE%[K")%\n%
    )%\n%
    Endlocal%\n%
  )Else Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion ^& Set Args=

rem // usage example
 %Print%{150;75;50}This is a Demo
 %Print%{140;60;120} of same line multicolor output.\n
 %Print%{75;190;150}Includes End Of Line marker.
 Timeout 1 /NoBreak > Nul
 %Erase%{marker.}
 %Print%{150;150;80}marker and erase macro.\n
```