# IF cancels when I run message command to user

Tags: command-line, batch-file

Windows 10 x64 system

I made a batch file that checks audio file extensions inside a folder.

When I run the command that will send the alert message outside the IF statement, the message is displayed without errors:

Command outside the IF statement:

```
@echo off
 SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
   for /F %d in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do (set "ESC=%d")
   echo %ESC%[91mATTENTION, file extension WAV not found! Do you want to look for another file? (y=return/n=exit)%ESC%[0m

set /p r=
IF /i "%r%"=="n" goto searchfile 
goto exit
```

Output command in screen terminal:
[image]

Command inside the IF statement:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Audios Files\WAV" ( 
echo.-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.                  WAV extension not found or there was some error in the Audio  
echo.-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F %d in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do (set "ESC=%d")
echo %ESC%[91mExtension not found or in error! Do you want to look for another file? (y=return/n=exit)%ESC%[0m

set /p r=""
IF /i "%r%"=="s" goto EXT 
goto notfound
)

:notfound
exit
```

Output command inside the IF statement:

```
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Files\WAV" (
More? echo.-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
More? echo. ATTENTION, file extension WAV not found! 
More? echo.-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
More? @echo off
More?  SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
More?    for /F %d in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do (set "ESC=%d")
Mais?    echo %ESC%[91mATTENTION, file not found! Do you want to look for another file? (y=return/n=exit)%ESC%[0m
%ESC%[0m it was unexpected at this time.
```

Error message on command execution:
`%ESC%[0m it was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: Use: `echo. <long spaces> <text>` and see the results changes...

Comment: @iTwasnTme your tip really eliminated the duplicate lines, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [`SETLOCAL`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html): *Set options to control the visibility of environment variables **in a batch file**.* No effect in `cmd`…
2. `ECHO OFF`: No effect in `cmd`…
3. You need to [escape some characters](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) in `ECHO`; in particular, all closing parentheses…
4. `%ECHO%` variable is expanded at parse time (like all other percent-expanded variables). Declare and define it *before* used inside a parenthesized command like `if`.

With escaped closing parenthesis:

```
set "ESC="
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Files\WAV" (
More?   echo.-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
More?   echo. ATTENTION, file extension WAV not found!
More?   echo.-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
More?   REM we need to escape closing parenthesis  ↓
More?   echo %ESC%[91mATTENTION, … (y=return/n=exit^)%ESC%[0m
More? )
```

> ```
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  ATTENTION, file extension WAV not found!
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> %ESC%[91mATTENTION, … (y=return/n=exit)%ESC%[0m
> ```

With properly declared and defined `ECHO` variable: the text in ANSI escape sequence `ATTENTION, … (y=return/n=exit)` shows in red:

```
for /F %d in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do (set "ESC=%d")
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Files\WAV" (
More?   echo.-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
More?   echo. ATTENTION, file extension WAV not found!
More?   echo.-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
More?   REM we need to escape closing parenthesis  ↓
More?   echo %ESC%[91mATTENTION, … (y=return/n=exit^)%ESC%[0m
More? )
```

> ```
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  ATTENTION, file extension WAV not found!
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ATTENTION, … (y=return/n=exit)
> ```

**EDIT**. Of course, **inside a batch script**:

- you can apply [Delayed Expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and refer to the `ESC` variable as `!ESC!` instead of `%ESC%` (you can see it in my [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/1576579/376602)), and
- double the percent sign to denote a `for` variable `%d` as follows:

```
for /F %%d in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do (set "ESC=%%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

correcting the answer.
I removed the parentheses in y=return/n=exit and the warning message no longer appeared.

Now only the message color does not change when the command is inside the If. I will check it out.

**EDIT:**
The color issue in the message was also resolved with the answer, in this post, from user @JosefZ.

Comment: Please note that **no site is a chat at  https://stackexchange.com/ network**.   Please [edit your original question](https://superuser.com/posts/1714134/edit) to improve it…